# get datetime difference of a specific time and value of date time column

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime column in my mysql table.
I need to get the difference between a definite time everyday say 12.00 pm and the value of that column.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was trickier than I expected (been a while since I've used the date and time functions) - so I did the following.

Created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE times (t timestamp);
```

Then put in some random data:

```
INSERT INTO times VALUES ('2016-06-27 01:01:12');
INSERT INTO times VALUES ('2016-06-27 07:34:17');
INSERT INTO times VALUES ('2016-06-27 14:56:03');
INSERT INTO times VALUES ('2016-06-27 23:24:56');
```

And then ran the best function that I could find:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t, '2016-06-27 12:00:00') AS tdiff FROM times;
```

And obtained the result (correct - in minutes):

```
tdiff
-----
658
265
-176
-684
```

You can, of course, divide (or multiply) by whatever factor you choose to convert the outputs to the units of your choice.

Depending on your needs, these might suit you better:

```
- SELECT TIMEDIFF(t, '2016-06-27 12:00:00') AS tdiff FROM times;

- SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-06-27 12:00:00') AS tdiff FROM times;

- SELECT TO_SECONDS(t) - TO_SECONDS('2016-06-27 12:00:00') AS tdiff FROM times;
```

Following @AndrewBrennan's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/142339/34007) below, I've expanded on it somewhat - i.e. if one wished to run the query over a period of a week/month/quarter - whatever. It will perform the relevant calculation comparing datetimes on a given day in the datetime field with the fixed `definite time` - i.e. comparing like with like on the particular day in question.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 
                     t, 
                     CONCAT(YEAR(t), '-',  
                            MONTH(t), '-', 
                            DAY(t), 
                            ' 12:00:00'))
AS tdiff
FROM times;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
select TIMEDIFF(time1,time2) as Difference from your_table_name
```

Here `time1` is actual time in your case 12.00 PM and time2 is column name of datetime column

Answer (score 2):

Use timestampdiff() to get the time difference, and curdate() to get today's date. You can concatenate the output of curdate() to a string containing the specific time you want to subtract from:

> select timestampdiff( MINUTE, your_column, concat( curdate(), ' 12:00:00' )) from your_table;

Timestampdiff documentation is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: +1 - really like the curdate() - means that the query doesn't have to be changed on a daily basis - always assuming that it's only today that the comparison is being made for.